# Excel VBA troubles with worksheet activation to paste data

Tags: excel, vba

I do have a problem activating a workbook in the middle of a VBA code:
The idea is to Open New file->User enters a new name for that file (mainWB)->Rename the file->Choose other xlsx files from a folder -> for each file selected:

- open file
- select and copy all data from the first sheet
- open mainWB
- create a new sheet
- paste data copied
- rename sheet with AF2.value

close all files selected previously.

So far I have:

```
Sub OpenSelectedFiles()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim SelectedFile As Integer
Dim FileName As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook
Dim MainWB As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim oldName As String
Dim newName As String

oldName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
newName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Nombre del Nuevo Archivo:")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs newName
newName=ActiveWorkbook.Name
Kill oldName

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

fd.InitialFileName = "Libraries\Documents"
fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

SelectedFile = fd.Show
If SelectedFile = -1 Then
    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
        Set TempWB = Workbooks.Open(fd.SelectedItems(i))
        Call CopyFromOpenFile(TempWB)
    Next i
End If
Dim openWB As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each openWB In Application.Workbooks
    If Not (openWB Is Application.ActiveWorkbook) Then
        openWB.Close
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub CopyFromOpenFile(src As Workbook)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy

    Windows(newName).Activate 'Here Excel gives me an error, I cannot activate it to paste the data from the other files 

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Name = Range("AF2").Value

End Sub

End Sub
```

If someone has an ideia on how to solve it i'll appreciate a lot.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: And where do you use `src` in your `CopyFromOpenFile` subroutine? `newName` isn't a global variable here, so you're not passing it from `OpenSelectedFile` to that sub.

Comment: @dwirony just global newName as string should do the trick?

Comment: Just move `Dim newname as String` above `Sub OpenSelectedFiles()`. You only need it at the module level - if you need it for all modules, you'd move it up there and change it to `Public newname as String`.

Comment: Thank you @dwirony, it worked!